# AngularJS route provider - post request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I do a post request to a url using routeprovider?   Provided sample code below

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.htm"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.htm"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.htm"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.htm"
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try templateUrl : "http://www.YourURL.com/MyPage.htm"

Comment: talking about post request  to  "YourURL.com/MyPage.htm"  where do you specify httpd method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `resolve`:

```
.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "main.htm",
    resolve: {
      data: function($http) {
        $http.post('/yourUrl', yourData)
            .then(function(res) {
              return res;
            }, function(err) {
              console.log(err);
              return null;
            })
    }
    }
})
```

And then in your controller,

```
.controller(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
 })
```

**NOTE:** This is not using *routeProvider* per se, because making REST calls is not what the routeProvider is for. Angular can do that only through the `$http` service. I am assuming that you just want to make a REST call from within your route definition.

**Protip** A better way of doing this would be to define a service in your module, and insert the *module* in the route resolve, rather than injecting `$http` directly. I've done that here only for brevity

Comment: Thanks for the info.   Will you be able to help me out this query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40231503/dynamic-html-angular-js